Reading ranges of bytes of a GZIP file in JAVA 8
I am trying to read a gz file in Java 8, that has been divided into chunks, then write the decompressed data (using a BufferedWriter) to a file. For example:
range=0-100, range=101-202, and so on.
My first question is: Is it possible to do it the way I presented?
My seconds question: If it is possible, what am I doing wrong?
From what I have understood from other forums, I need a GZIPInputStream and a ByteArrayOutputStream to decompress the bytes. My problem is that after successfully writing the first chunk (the one containing the GZIP_HEADER), I will get this error for the remaining chunks:
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format => due to the header not being present
I have tried to use a GZIPOutputStream to basically recreate a valid gz file (add the gzipHeader to the compressed data), but I will get these errors:
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
This is what I have tried in the Main class:
byte[] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
System.out.println("File data size: " + fileData.length);
int chunkSize = fileData.length / 5; // dividing the file into 5 equal parts

// Iterate over the chunks
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     int startIndex = i * chunkSize;
     int endIndex = Math.min((i + 1) * chunkSize, fileData.length);

     // Extract the chunk from the file data
     byte[] chunk = new byte[endIndex - startIndex];
     System.arraycopy(fileData, startIndex, chunk, 0, endIndex - startIndex);
     if (i != 0) {
        chunk = decompressor.addGzipHeader(chunk);
     }

     try {
        byte[] decompressedData = decompressor.decompress(chunk);
        System.out.println("Successfully written chunk " + i);
        bufferedWriter.write(new String(decompressedData));
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
bufferedWriter.close();

This is what I have tried in the Decompressor class:
public byte[] addGzipHeader(byte[] compressedData) throws IOException {
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   // Write gzip header bytes to the ByteArrayOutputStream
   byteArrayOutputStream.write(this.gzipHeader);

   // Write compressed data to the ByteArrayOutputStream
   byteArrayOutputStream.write(compressedData);

   return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
public byte[] decompress(byte[] compressedData) throws IOException {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

   try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedData);
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = gzipInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1 && byteArrayInputStream.available() > 0) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}

Thank you so much for your time!

I am trying to read a gz file in Java 8, that has been divided into chunks That's not clear. How has it been "divided into chunks" - how does gzip support that?

You're right. It is not the best explanation. It is not divided. The file itself is whole and I am trying to read a byte array received from an s3 GetObjectRequest. If this needs further information, I can provide the getObjectBytes method:
https://pastebin.com/rTCzYqk7

So the file is a regular gzip file?  What is gained by dividing it into fifths?

Yes. The file is a gz file stored in s3. The snippet provided only simulates the flow of the main project, therefore I just happened to "divide" a local gz file into fifths.:) The idea is that a consumer will consume the decompressed data which will be stored in a queue.

So you just need to provide the data in decompressed form to a consumer?

Yes. I need to push the data to a queue after decompressing. The errors happen in the decompressing phase due to the "dividing".

You can't decompress each chunk independently. The last few bytes of chunk N may well be telling the decompressor what to do with the first few bytes of chunck N+1. You need to concatenate the chunks, decompress them as one, and then, if you need to, you can re-chunk the result.

I was thinking about that as well. Thank you all!

Sounds like you need to do some more thinking first. One thing that seems pretty certain is that you will be dealing with large files, so you don't want to tax memory unnecessarily. You will probably need to know the uncompressed size too, which you can get with public static long getUncompressedSize(Path p) throws IOException {try (GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(Files.newInputStream(p));OutputStream out = OutputStream.nullOutputStream()) {return in.transferTo(out);}}

@g00se that actually reads the whole file and counts the bytes. The OP is getting the file in chunks from AWS S3, so won't have a Path. Also, if it requires downloading the whole file just to get the size, you might as well process it while downloading it. By the way, the uncompressed size is stored in the last 4 bytes of the file (if it's less than 4GB), so the way to do it is to download the last chunk and look at the last 4 bytes.

@k314159 is right. I am now thinking of another way to process the data thanks to your response.

@k314159, right, yes. It was confusing about what's going on. You're right about the last four bytes of .gz. Unfortunate that the JDK doesn't deal with that by the looks

Use a concatenated input stream on the parts and wrap it with your GZipInputStream. The first part contains the header, the others do not. Then when you create the parts, you take the compressed data as-is and simply partition it in chunks (split the file). When you combine them, you read them in sequence with the SequenceInputStream, so that the GZipInputStream sees all the bytes of the full file without knowing there are any parts at all.
This assumes the chunks have been created by simply splitting the full file, but I believe that is the common approach.

Thanks for your answer! The code snippet I provided is an isolated part of a bigger project. The main idea is that I receive a range of bytes from an s3Object and send the byte array to a method (let's call it processBytes) for further processing. The processBytes decompresses the provided byte array then adds the decompressed content in a queue (a consumer will take items from the queue). I am doing it this way because the order of the bytes do not matter. Is there a way to do it as I presented?

You would need a SequenceOutputStream for this, were there such a thing, but there isn't

From what I can tell, you don’t need to divide your file at all.
You don’t need to use any byte arrays.  You don’t need to use any ByteArrayOutputStreams.  Just copy the GZIPInputStream to a file:
Path uncompressedFile = /* ... */;

try (InputStream uncompressed = new GZIPInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(
        Files.newInputStream(filePath)))) {

    Files.copy(uncompressed, uncompressedFile,
        StandardCopyOptions.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

I recommend that you avoid byte arrays as much as possible.  Pass data around as a Path or InputStream instead.
If the data is very large, returning the entire contents as a byte array will cause your program to become a very large process, eating up system resources and slowing down the machine on which it’s running.  InputStream (and all file functions that return data sequentially, a concept which existed long before Java) exists precisely to let programs avoid that problem.
